# javascript tab doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

i am a new learner of javascript. so the first i don't want to use jquery to get the tab. the following is my code. but it doesn't work.how to correct my code. thank you.

```
.web_index{ position:relative;}
.web_index div{ width:400px; height:300px; background:#eee; position:absolute; left:30px;top:100px; }
ul li{ float: left; width:100px; height:30px; line-height:30px; list-style:none;}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function clicker(){
        var lier=document.getElementsByTagName("li");
        var diver=document.getElementsByClassName("web_index").getElementsByTagName("div");

        for(var i=0;i<lier.length;i++){
            for(j=0;j<diver.length;j++){
                if(i==j)
                    diver[j].style.display=block;
                }else{
                    diver[j].style.display=none;
                }   
            }
        }
    }   
</script>

</head>

<body >
<ul>
    <li onclick="clicker()" class="li01">one</li>
    <li onclick="clicker()" class="li02">two</li>
    <li onclick="clicker()" class="li03">three</li>
    <div class="web_clear"></div>
</ul>
<div class="web_index">
<div style="display:block" >content one</div>
<div style="display:none">content two</div>
<div style="display:none">content three</div>
</div>
```

i want to when click `one` then show `content one`.all the content are hidden. two then show `content two`...

Comment: There are a lot of jQuery tab plugins like http://www.techlaboratory.net/products.php?product=smarttab

Comment: As a general comment: always include: What should happen? How does it not work? What did you try?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: i want to when click one then show content one.all the content are hidden. two then show content two...

Comment: @downa1234 You can pass `ID`s to the function and make it work. :) It is a simple and the best way.

Comment: many thanks, if i want to use my code. how to correct it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

See, for your question of implementing tabs, I can suggest you to do in a better way. The same clicker function can take an argument of the `ID` of the `DIV` and you can pass it when you are calling it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>Tabs</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <style type="text/css">
    .web_index div {width: 400px; height: 300px; background: #eee;}
    ul li{width: 100px; height: 30px; line-height: 30px; list-style: none; display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1;}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
    <li onclick="clicker(1)">one</li>
    <li onclick="clicker(2)">two</li>
    <li onclick="clicker(3)">three</li>
</ul>
<div class="web_index">
  <div id="t1">content one</div>
  <div id="t2">content two</div>
  <div id="t3">content three</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clicker(tab){
      document.getElementById("t1").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("t2").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("t3").style.display = "none";

      document.getElementById("t" + tab).style.display = "block";
    }
    clicker(1);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Working

Instead of finding the `index` of the element occurrence, we can give a Unique ID to each. Then, functions support arguments, and that is what javascripts are for. Pass that argument and set the style using `.style.display` of the element.

We don't need to position the tabs as absolute, because it is not going to be hanging. And, you can set the margins using `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left`.

```
.web_index div {width: 400px; height: 300px; background: #eee;}
ul li {width: 100px; height: 30px; line-height: 30px; list-style: none; display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1;}
```

You can rewrite the `clicker()` script this way:

```
function clicker(tab){
  document.getElementById("t1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("t2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("t3").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("t" + tab).style.display = "block";
}
```

So that, you can pass the `ID` of the `DIV` tag as a parameter. By modifying the `style` properties of the element, you can either hide or show.

You can call this in the `<li>` using the same `onclick` function but just passing another extra parameter:

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="clicker(1)">one</li>
    <li onclick="clicker(2)">two</li>
    <li onclick="clicker(3)">three</li>
</ul>
```

#### Check out demo at: http://jsbin.com/welcome/22513